# Inject repository in service without DI framework

Tags: dependency-injection, repository, jax-rs

I have a requirement to create a simple REST API with basic CRUD operations on a resource, without using Spring but just Java.I use JAX-RS (Jersey implementation) and Jetty as an embedded servlet container.I use JPA (Hibernate implementation) and an H2 in-memory database. I don't use any DI framework so I do all the DI "manually" with new().

Below is a JAX-RS service that has a POST endpoint. I have created the repository as a static final variable inside the service. BookRepository is an interface and BookRepositoryImpl is the implementation of this repository. I wonder if this is the best approach. If I did this with Spring Autowired annotation, I would have a singleton repository so the only way I thought to emulate this is with a static final variable. 
When the container runs, does a separate instance of the BookService gets created for each request (thread)? 
So multiple threads will have access to a single copy of the bookRepository?
Isn't that what happens with the Autowired and singleton scope?

```
@Path("/books")
public class BookService {

private static final BookRepository bookRepository = new BookRepositoryImpl();

@POST
@Path("")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Book registerBook(Book b) {
    return bookRepository.saveBook(b);
}
}
```

Comment: You're not actually using DI. If you were, the dependency would be coming through the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying Dependency Injection without a DI Container is a practice commonly referred to as [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di//). With that approach you apply the same principles, practices, and patterns of object-oriented design and DI. But instead of wiring everything up using a DI Container, at the startup path of the application, you build your object graphs manually, using the `new` keyword.

Pure DI is a common—and valid—approach of practicing DI—DI Containers are useful, but *optional* tools.

This, however, is not the approach you are currently practicing. You are *not* injecting your dependencies into their consumers. By creating `BookRepositoryImpl` inside the `BookService` class, you are applying the [Control Freak anti-pattern](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-5/section-5-1), with is a special form of a [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) violation. This tightly couples the `BookRepositoryImpl` class to the `BookService` class, which will likely cause maintainability issues, because `BookRepositoryImpl` is a [Volatile Dependency](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2006/08/24/volatile-dependencies/). Volatile Dependencies are the reason we introduce abstractions and use Dependency Injection.

Besides, the use of static fields only magnifies the pain, because this might cause thread-safety issues in case `BookRepositoryImpl` (or one of its dependencies) isn't thread-safe.

So, instead of tightly coupling `BookRepositoryImpl` to `BookService`, you should inject the `BookRepository` abstraction into the `BookService`'s constructor. This keeps the two components loosely coupled, and gives you all the benefits that loose coupling brings:

```cs
@Path("/books")
public class BookService {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Book registerBook(Book b) {
        return bookRepository.saveBook(b);
    }
}
```

This does mean, however, that you should override the way your REST API web framework creates that service. Such framework is typically only able to create instances on your behalf if they have a default constructor. I must admit that I have no experience with JAX-RS, but most frameworks allow overriding the creation of their root classes. With the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC framework, for instance, you can implement a custom `IControllerFactory`, and replace the framework's default implementation. Inside your custom factory, you will create the complete tree by hand, with plain old Java.

```
public object create(Type controllerType)
{
    if (controllerType == typeof(HomeService))
        return
            new HomeService(
                new PersonsRepositoryImpl(this.connectionString));

    if (controllerType == typeof(BookService))
        return
            new BookService(
                new BookRepositoryImpl(this.connectionString));

    if (...)

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown type.");
}
```

My expectation is that JAX-RS contains a similar extension model, which allows you to practice Pure DI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steven for the answer. To conclude, this is the JAX-RS config where I am doing the DI:

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public AppConfig() {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-unit");

        BookRepository bookRepository = new BookRepositoryImpl(emf);

        BookService bookService = new BookService(bookRepository);

        register(bookService);

  }
}
```